# C# Why string.format round float values to nearest 10th?

Tags: c#, rounding

Following number when formatted it rounds up to nearest 10th value

```
var testVal = Convert.ToSingle("10963798");
var formattedVal = string.Format("{0:n0}", testVal);
```

**Output:** 10,963,800

How can I avoid this round up?

Comment: `float` only has 7 digits of precision.  So use `double` or `decimal` if you need more.

Comment: agree @juharr. Besides floating point have representation problem: not every number exist, like 0,7 etc

Comment: @JacekCz For decimal accuracy `decimal` is the best choice, but here it could even just be an `int` as others have mentioned.  The OP just needs to read up on the limitations of the various number types and pick the one that fits the situation best.

Comment: You are using the wrong data type - replace `Single` with something wider.

Comment: Note that `Console.WriteLine(10963798f.ToString("G9"));` does, in fact, print `10963798`.

Comment: It looks like this is a quirk of the formatting - maybe related to the "G" format displaying single precision numbers to 7 digit accuracy by default. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#RFormatString

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ToSingle` returns a single-precision `float`, which doesn't have that kind of precision (just 7 decimal digits usually). For this reason, `Format` assumes that the last digit is imprecise, and rounds it to 0.

Use `ToDouble` instead, which returns a `double`.

Or, because you're not using any fractional part, just use `ToInt32`.

Comment: The value 10963798 is actually exactly representable in a `float`, as are all integer values up to 16777216. This is a quirk of how `.Format` rounds, under the *assumption* that the value won't be exact.

Comment: @JeroenMostert As proved  by `Console.WriteLine(10963798f.ToString("G9"))`